# Why is this code not going into an infinite loop as suggested by JSR133?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, volatile, java-memory-model

In [JSR-133 section 3.1](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/CommunityReview.pdf), which discusses the visibility of actions between threads - it is mentioned that the code example below, which does not utilise the volatile keyword for the boolean field, can become an infinite loop if two threads are running it. Here is the code from the JSR:

```
class LoopMayNeverEnd {
    boolean done = false;
    void work() {
        while (!done) {
            // do work
        }
    }
    void stopWork() {
        done = true;
    }
}
```

Here is a quote of the important bit in that section that I'm interested in:

> ... Now imagine that two threads are created, and that one
>   thread calls work(), and at some point, the other thread calls stopWork(). Because there is
>   no happens-before relationship between the two threads, the thread in the loop may never
>   see the update to done performed by the other thread ...

And here is my own Java code I wrote just so I can see it loop:

```
public class VolatileTest {
    private boolean done = false;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        VolatileTest volatileTest = new VolatileTest();
        volatileTest.runTest();
    }
    private void runTest() {
        Thread t1 = new Thread(() -> work());
        Thread t2 = new Thread(() -> stopWork());
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }
    private void stopWork() {
        done = true;
        System.out.println("stopped work");
    }
    private void work() {
        while(!done){
            System.out.println("started work");
        }
    }
}
```

Although the results from consecutive executions are different - as expected - I don't see it ever going into an infinite loop. I'm trying to understand how I can simulate the infinite loop that the documentation suggests, what am I missing? How does declaring the boolean *volatile*, remove the infinite loop?

Comment: Remove your println statements, and you'll probably have a program that never stops. But even if you don't, remember that just because something *can* happen, even once in a million times, doesn't mean that it will always happen. It can depend on your JVM, your OS, etc. You just don't have any guarantee that the thread will see the new boolean value. Which is very different from saying "you are guaranteed that the thread won't see it".

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Removing the print statement in the while loop is enough to get it into an infinite loop... Now the program prints "stopped work" and then never ends. Where did the assignment to the boolean variable to true go?

Comment: It went to the register, or memory cache of the CPU core used by the stopping thread, or even to the main memory. But the reading thread can continue to read it from its own CPU core memory cache, because the field is not marked as volatile.

Comment: That makes sense. Final question, does declaring the boolean a volatile mean that stopWork() is always called first due to the happens-before relationship?

Comment: No, not at all. It guarantees that if a thread has written a value to the volatile field, then another thread reading the vaue of the volatile field will see the written value, and not some previous value.

Comment: Great - thanks a lot!

Comment: @JBNizet you could fill books with the meaning of “then” in your statement. As the only guaranty is that a *subsequent* read will see the most recently written value whereas “subsequent” is referring to the *synchronization order*. In absence of any other synchronization action, the only way to find out whether the read was subsequent to a particular write, is by examining the read value, which makes the guaranty much weaker than often thought.

Comment: @Holger Hmm. I'm certainly not competent enough to fill that book, but I've always thought that "subsequent" (or "then", in my poor terminology) meant basically what it means in common English, i.e. "after". Isn't there a guarantee that, in absence of any other synchronization mechanism, a thread reading the volatile field will see the write that another thread has done "before" (or at least, sufficiently before)? Are you implying that stopping a thread by setting a volatile flag only works by accident?

Comment: @JBNizet the meaning in common English is tied to the “wall clock time”, which has no meaning to Java’s execution at all. There is no guaranty about how long the execution of a particular statement will take and there are little guarantees about thread scheduling. It is reasonable to assume that a loop polling a `volatile` variable will *eventually* proceed, if the thread gets the CPU. Though, in this specific example involving two threads of equal priority, it would be within the specification if the polling thread eats all CPU cycles, preventing the other thread from ever making the write.

Comment: OK, that was my understanding. But if the thread scheduler never allows one of the thread to run, then the term "subsequent read" is irrelevant anyway, since there is no read at all, or no write at all. If the thread scheduler gives the opportunity to both threads to run, and the write completed before the read, then the reader is guaranteed to see the written value, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

The actual behavior is OS and JVM specific. For example, by default, Java runs in client mode on 32-bit Windows and in server mode on the Mac. In **client mode** the `work` method will terminate, but will not terminate in **server mode**.

This happens because of the Java server JIT compiler optimization. The JIT compiler may optimize the while loop, because it does not see the variable `done` changing within the context of the thread. Another reason of the infinite loop might be because one thread may end up reading the value of the flag from its registers or cache instead of going to memory. As a result, it may never see the change made by the another thread to this flag.

Essentially by adding `volatile` you make the thread owning `done` flag to not cache this flag. Thus, the `boolean` value is stored in common memory and therefore guarantees *visibility*. Also, by using `volatile` you disabling JIT optimization that can inline the flag value.

Basically if you want to reproduce infinite loop - just run your program in server mode:

```
java -server VolatileTest
```

Comment: Adding -server as a vm argument didn't create an infinite loop

Answer (score 1):

The default, non-volatile, implicit declaration of all Java values allows the Jit compiler to "hoist" references to non-volatile values, out of loops so that they are only read 'once'.  This is allowed after a tracing of execution paths can safely arrive at the fact that the methods called inside of such a loop, don't ever cause entry back into the classes methods where it might mutate the value of these non-volatile values.

The System.out.println() invocation goes to native code which keeps the JIT from resolving that 'done' is never modified.  Thus the hoist does not happen when the System.out.println() is there and as you found out, the infinite loop is only happening with it removed where the JIT can resolve that there is no write to 'done'.

The ultimate problem is that this reference hoisting is conditional on "reachability" of a mutation of the value.  Thus, you may have moments where there is no reach to a mutation of the value, during development, and thus the hoist happens and suddenly you can't exit the loop.  A later change to the loop might use some function that makes it impossible to discern that the value cannot be written by the logic in the loop, and the hoist disappears and the loop works again.

This hoist is a big problem for many people who don't see it coming. There is a pretty large group of belief now that safe Java has class level variables either declared as volatile or final.  If you really need a variable to be "optimizable", then don't use a class level variable and instead make it a parameter, or copy it into a local variable for the optimizer to go after. Doing this with read only access helps manage "dynamic" changes in a value that disrupt predictable execution paths too.

There is has been recurring discussion on the java concurrency mailing list about this issue.  They don't seem to believe that this is a problem for Java developers and that this "optimization" of reference is far more valuable to performance than problematic to development.